# How do I filter exposed taxonomy terms with other exposed taxonomy terms?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

OK, so I have 3 different Taxonomy Vocabularies filled like this: One for Carriers [AT&T, T-Mobile] One for Manufacturers [Samsung, iPhone, etc] And one for the Models [Galaxy S3, S4, etc]

All of these are set as an Exposed Filter for a custom view, But what I want is for the last Exposed Filter, "Models" to be Filtered by whatever Selection is made in "Manufacturers"

So if I Select iPhone, I only see Models for iPhones.

I've searched everywhere without the solution I need. And if it is what I needed, I wasn't able to set it up, or directions weren't clear enough.

I have Term References Linked from the Models to the Manufacturers, but idk how to Filter the Exposed Filter to only show Model choices for the selected manufacturer.

How do I filter exposed taxonomy terms with other exposed taxonomy terms?
Any help is appreciated!

I'm Working with Drupal 7.

Comment: As @heart.cooks.mind already suggested, one option would be to use Search API. The keyword you are looking for is however Faceted Search, this is what describes the functionality you described. Cheers!

Comment: I don't see how I can Filter Selectable Taxonomy Terms with it though.
I have 3 selectable [Exposed] content Filters coming from 3 different Taxonomy Vocabs. Each one has it's own Vocab, and I want the Second Vocab Term choice to Limit the amounts to the last one based on Term References.

So if I select iPhone Term for the Manufacturers Vocab, then I want the Model Vocab Content Filter to only List iPhone Models, even though that Vocab contains Terms for Many different Models.

Vocab 2: Manufacturers:
 Terms:
   iPhone
   Samsung

Vocab 3: Models
 Terms:
   iPhone 4
   Galaxy 3

Comment: I don't want people to be able to Select "Manufacturer: iPhone" & "Model: Galaxy S3" cause that wouldn't Make any sense.

My View Looks like this: http://s1345.photobucket.com/user/Lilith_Anthel/media/2016-06-02%201_zpsyzzgzfc1.png.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Search API.  Totally awesome.  It will provide you with the Facets you need.  Don't be intimidated.  The instructions below are great.

http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr/

Comment: view looks like this http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p673/Lilith_Anthel/2016-06-02%201_zpsyzzgzfc1.png 

When I search for things, it works, trouble is I want the last 
"Content: Has taxonomy term (exposed)" to be Limited by the Second
"Content: Has taxonomy term (exposed)"

View render: http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p673/Lilith_Anthel/2016-06-02_zpsx35p1w5f.png

So when I select "iPhone" in the Second 
"Content: Has taxonomy term"
The Last "Content: Has taxonomy term"
Only will show iPhone Models as a Result, instead of ALL of the Phone Models I have in the Taxonomy Terms

Comment: If you use the Search API, it provides the Facets as blocks for you based on the Fields you choose to Index.  If you want your facets in drop down select boxes as shown in your photo, you would want this additional module https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_select.  Each selection the user makes, will exclude options in the other boxes (that are no longer available).

Comment: "Each selection the user makes, will exclude options in the other boxes"
How? I'm not sure I get how to set this up properly

Answer (score 0):

Simple Hierarchical Select did the trick, I just need to Combine the Manufacturers & Models list, and make the Models Childs to the Manufacturers, so when I select Samsung, it poofs another dropdown that lets me Select the Samsung children I set up in the Taxonomy Terms! I set Depth to -1

I tried to get it to work earlier to no avail, but it works now!
Found out it was Conflicting with another Module.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be this module : [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters)

A new kind of filter is available in the Views listing (named "your field (selective filter)". You may add three selective filters, each related to a vocabulary (even different ones). When you select a value in the first filter, the two others will only suggest possible values for contents with the first tag.